# What are the parameters for a GridLayout?

Tags: java, layout, grid-layout

```
private static final GridLayout layout = new GridLayout( 3, 1, 1, 0 );
```

in this line of code what do the numbers represent and how do you use them to arrange the checkboxes and buttons in the window?

Answer (score 9):

The [GridLayout](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/GridLayout.html) class:

```
public GridLayout(int rows,
                  int cols,
                  int hgap,
                  int vgap)

Creates a grid layout with the specified number of rows and columns. All components in the layout are given equal size.
In addition, the horizontal and vertical gaps are set to the specified values. Horizontal gaps are placed between each of the columns. Vertical gaps are placed between each of the rows.

One, but not both, of rows and cols can be zero, which means that any number of objects can be placed in a row or in a column.

All GridLayout constructors defer to this one.

Parameters:
rows - the rows, with the value zero meaning any number of rows
cols - the columns, with the value zero meaning any number of columns
hgap - the horizontal gap
vgap - the vertical gap
```

Answer (score 6):

I refer you to: http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/GridLayout.html